# Wicket span tag with RadioChoice

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a radio choice form which is generated with the RadioChoice component in wicket. Here `<span/>` covers all of the possible choices in the form. I want the span to go downwards. One option per row on screen, but I am currently stuck with the problem that if i try to style `choice` it get styled as one. For example, if i try to take `border: 1px solid red;` it creates only one border, and not one for each choice.

```
<form class="mapSelector" wicket:id="radioForm">
    <span class="choice" wicket:id="radio"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understood . You can't give style in `Span` because generation will be like `<span " wicket:id="radio">
        <input type="radio">choice  1</input>
        <input type="radio">choice 2</input>
    </span>` So you have to give style for radio . You can try inline style like  `span.input[type="radio"]{border: 1px solid red; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean with `I want the span to go downwards. One option per row on screen` but it sounds like you need a `<div>` instead of `<span>`, i.e. an element with `display:block`.

I am not sure how CSS `border` is related to `downwards` and `row`.

I'd suggest you to see what is the generated HTML because this Wicket Component may generate `<label>` too for each radio element.